# sqlite on Heroku (production, in memory)

Tags: ruby, sqlite, heroku

We want to use sqlite, via the sqlite3 gem in Ruby in a production app on Heroku. However, heroku detects the gem, and blocks our deploys.

We're aware heroku's filesystem is ephemeral, but we're using SQLLite's in memory mode for a short lived database in a background worker. Heroku blocks the gem because they worry people will attempt to use it as a persistent database and be surprised when their data disappears (see link below). I can appreciate their concern, but we have a legitimate use case, and are still blocked.

Are there are any work arounds to the nanny-check heroku adds if you have a legitimate use case for sqlite?

Edit: Please note, we are not looking for alternative tool suggestions. We already have a "real" database with terabytes of data. We're loading data into a local temp DB as a legit optimization. sqlite lite works great on Heroku using any other language binding. I'm just looking for a way around Heroku's nanny-check to use Ruby + sqlite.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, Heroku doesn't support SQLite on its architecture basis. You should migrate to PostgreSQL. But I know the solution without migrating - Dokkur - Heroku analogue.

Comment: We need in-memory tables. I love postgres, and we use it for our "real" database, but we really do just need short lived local sqlite tables in this use case.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you have a lot of options here. Heroku doesn't allow the use of SQLite.

You can still use a PG table as a generic, short-lived, database. Or if you just need a simple storage and you don't need advanced querying mechanisms, you can use Redis.

Both are available from Heroku.

Comment: We need a local, in-memory option for some aggressive number crunching. Adding a remote database is overkill, not fast enough and really the wrong tool for the job. Thanks though.

Comment: @simonie not looking for faster. sqlite is a very differnt tool compared to redis. It's serverless, in process, supports SQL, temporary tables, and paging to disk.